# Amazon Load Balancer - how to limit a url to a single virtual host

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

We're having an issue with our WordPress installation,  hosted on Amazon EC2. The problem is due to the fact that it's not configured as a load-balanced application, so images loaded to once server don't show up if the request is balanced to another server. Since it's very low volume, I would like to limit the Amazon load-balancer to always forward the requests for that url only to single server. Is this doable?

Comment: But what is the purpose of the second server in this setup?

Comment: @dusan.bajic There's not much of point in the second server for the WordPress, to be honest. We have other applications that use it for scaleability and and redundancy, but the volume of hits on the WordPress blog doesn't justify two servers. What I ended up doing is just pointing the DNS directly to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't.

ELB supports sticky sessions (session affinity) where requests accompanied by the same session cookie will tend to be delivered to the same server... but there is no way to pin specific paths in the URL to a single server -- that's not the point of a load *balancer*.  All servers behind a given load balancer should be able to serve any request that arrives, otherwise the service is not being used as intended.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. What I ended up doing is just changing the DNS to point to the single server instead of the ELB.